# Add ether to existing contract

Tags: solidity, ether

What is the function syntax to add more ether to an existing contract?

My contract exists, with Ether, and I want to add more Ether via a function call to the contract. How do I do this?

Can it only be deducted from the sender/owner wallet?

Can I specify which wallet it is deducted from?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding Ether to a contract is similar to adding Ether to an account. Only difference is, you could combine adding Ether with an invoke of a function of the contract (So the function get invoked and you could carry out any task at the same time the Ether get added into the contract).

You should specify the Ether amount you need to send in Wei as the *value* of transaction along with *gasLimit, gasPrice etc* (More info could be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3abnim/how_to_initiate_a_contract_transaction_from/)). Further you should have a fallback function in the contract or the target function should be marked as *payable*.

Where you could deduct ether, You could deduct ether only from the senders account. But if you are transferring Ether from a contract to another contract or account, provided that contract is written in a way that it allows others to initiate transfers, you could deduct Ether from contract's balance.

Comment: Here is the trick, you should not send the ether value in a variable of the function(which goes into data attribute of the transaction message). It should be the value attribute of the transaction message. Once you do that, ether will be deducted from sender and added to the contract without you doing anything. If you need to access ether amount transfer within the function, use msg.value for that.

Comment: You have to use *sendTransaction* or *sendRawTransaction* function of the web3js module to achieve this. Check the transaction message structure. You would find some help at https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3abnim/how_to_initiate_a_contract_transaction_from/

Comment: You do not have to explicitly deduct any amount of account balance. Once you send a value to another contract, provided it is successful the amount get automatically deducted from source and added into the target.

Comment: If you mark your function as *payable*, still it should work.

Comment: I have updated the answer with more info which you shared in comments. Please consider accepting the answer as correct if you think you got all the info you need from that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot deduct from any other wallet, however other wallet can send Ether to your contract so that your contract can use it.

Comment: @MCloud The sending wallet has to send the ETH in the tx. The contract can't take ETH from the sending address without the address sending it in the tx.